# How to eliminate from a list [b,a] if already exist [a,b]

Tags: prolog

what I want to do is really simple: I already have a "function" that starting with a list (i.e. [a,b,c,d]) produces every combination of two different element that are in the list.

[a,b,c,d] -> [[a,b], [a,c], ... , [b,a], ... ]

```
fun(List, Res):-
    findall( [A, B],
             ( member(A, List), 
               member(B, List), 
               \+ A = B ), 
             Res ).
```

Now I need to check and delete every element that has the same atoms in them and it doesn't need to be ordinated.

([a,b]-<s>[b,a]</s> = [b,a]-<s>[a,b]</s>)

What I tried to do is simply add

```
fun(List, Res):-
    findall( [A, B],
             ( member(A, List), 
               member(B, List), 
               \+ A = B, 
               \+ member([B,A], Res)), % I TRIED TO ADD THIS
              Res).
```

Which I think you can't read *Res* directly inside the function.

Thanks.

Comment: You can also do `select(A, List, Rest), member(B, Rest)` to avoid `\+ A=B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the order does not matter, you can choose only pairs whose first element precedes the second one (in the [standard order of terms](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=standardorder)). Thus, supposing that all elements in the list are distinct, you can define the desired predicate as follows:

```
pairs(List, Pairs):-
    findall( [X, Y],
             ( member(X, List),
               member(Y, List),
               X @< Y ),
             Pairs ).
```

Example:

```
?- pairs([a, b, c, d], Pairs).
Pairs = [[a, b], [a, c], [a, d], [b, c], [b, d], [c, d]].

?- pairs([3, 1, 5], Pairs).
Pairs = [[3, 5], [1, 3], [1, 5]].
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. But I don't quite understand the role of the operator @<

Comment: @AlessandroMuscatello The goal `X @< Y` is true if `X` is before `Y` the standard order of terms (while the operator `<` can be used  only to compare numbers, the operator `@<`can be used to compare two terms of any type).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to generate the combinations of a list. That is to say, you want to select the distinct set of pairs from a given set of objects, where order is not important — that is, the combination `[1,2]` is the same combination as `[2,1]`.

For example, given the set `[1,2,3,4,5]`, the combinations of length 2 are as follows (since a "proper" combination does not allow duplicates such as `[2,2]`, given that the item has already been removed from the set):

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `[1,2]` | `[1,3]` | `[1,4]` | `[1,5]` |
| - | `[2,3]` | `[2,4]` | `[2,5]` |
| - | - | `[3,4]` | `[3,5]` |
| - | - | - | `[4,5]` |

If you want to allow duplicates, the set of pair-wise combinations is this:

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `[1,1]` | `[1,2]` | `[1,3]` | `[1,4]` | `[1,5]` |
| - | `[2,2]` | `[2,3]` | `[2,4]` | `[2,5]` |
| - | - | `[3,3]` | `[3,4]` | `[3,5]` |
| - | - | - | `[4,4]` | `[4,5]` |
| - | - | - | - | `[5,5]` |

The easiest way to accomplish this is to ... just generate the combinations properly. Much easier than then needed to remove the duplicates:

So, `select2` selects a combination of a particular size from a given list. On backtracking, it will successively return the remaining combinations.

**Note:** The second argument must be instantiated to an unbound list of the desired size:

```
select( _      , [] ) .
select( [X|Xs] , [X|Cs] ) :- select( Xs ,    Cs  ).
select( [_|Xs] , [X|Cs] ) :- select( Xs , [X|Cs] ).
```

To allow duplicates is a trivial change:

```
select( _      , []     ) .
select( [X|T]  , [X|Cs] ) :- select( [X|T] ,    Cs  ).
select( [_|T]  , [X|Cs] ) :- select(    T  , [X|Cs] ).
```

Whichever flavor you choose, Usage is simple:

```
Combination = [_,_], select([1,2,3,4,5],Combination).
```

which will return `Combination = [1,2]`, etc. until the possible solutions are exhausted.

You can wrap `select/2` to specify the desired size of the combination you'd like:

```
combination(N,Xs,C) :-
    length(Xs,L),     % how big is the source set?
    between(0,L,N),   % Ensure N > 0 and N <= L, the length of the source set
    length(C,N),      % create an unbound list of the desired length.
    select(Xs,C).     % and select a combination
```

Usage is simple:

```
combination(2,[1,2,3,4,5],Combination).
```

Also returns `Combination=[1,2]`, etc until the solution space is exhausted.

But given your use case where you want a list containing all the possible combinations, all you need is the base `select/2`:

```
findall( [A,B], select([1,2,3,4,5], [A,B]), Combinations ).
```

Which gives you the expected

```
Combinations=[
  [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [1, 5],
         [2,3], [2,4], [2, 5],
                [3,4], [3, 5],
                       [4, 5]
]
```